# Apache poi Style setting stops after a while

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

What I'm trying to do is to write a program that essentially translates an image into an Excel representation of that very image. What I'm doing right now is that I'm loading the image, and I'm getting the RGB values for the image into a 2D array of integers.

The issue that I'm facing is this. My cells suddenly have no styling! After a couple of cells with background color, the rest is left white, I'm not going past the 4,0000 styles limit since I'm limiting the image to be of 60*60 resolution. So I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

My main class:

```
package excelArtist;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

public class driver {

    static HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        imageHandler handler = new imageHandler("test.jpg");
        int[][] data = handler.convertImageToRGB();

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("drawing");

        // start drawing
        int width = handler.getWidth();
        int height = handler.getHeight();

        Row r;
        Cell c;
        HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();
        HSSFColor color;

        System.out.println("Width: " + width);
        System.out.println("Height: " + height);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            r = sheet.createRow(y);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int index = (y * width) + x;
                palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index,
                        (byte) data[index][0], (byte) data[index][1],
                        (byte) data[index][2]);
                color = palette.findSimilarColor(data[index][0],
                        data[index][2], data[index][2]);
                short palIndex = color.getIndex();
                c = r.createCell(x);
                c.setCellValue("0");
                HSSFCellStyle tempStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                tempStyle.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);
                tempStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                c.setCellStyle(tempStyle);
                System.out.println("Going through array index: " + index);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

}
```

my imageHandler class:

```
package excelArtist;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import net.coobird.thumbnailator.Thumbnails;

public class imageHandler {

    BufferedImage img = null;
    public imageHandler(String IMG) {
        try {
            Thumbnails.of(new File(IMG))
            .size(25, 25)
            .toFile(new File("resized"+IMG));

            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resized"+IMG));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int[][] convertImageToRGB() {

        int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()][3];
        int[] rgb;

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {
                rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for (int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++) {
                    pixelData[counter][k] = rgb[k];
                }

                counter++;
            }
        }

        return pixelData;
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return img.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return img.getHeight();
    }

    private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
        int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);

        int rgb[] = new int[] { (argb >> 16) & 0xff, // red
                (argb >> 8) & 0xff, // green
                (argb) & 0xff // blue
        };

        //System.out.println("rgb: " + rgb[0] + " " + rgb[1] + " " + rgb[2]);
        return rgb;
    }

}
```

EDIT: newly updated code

driver:

```
package excelArtist;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class driver {

    static XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    static HSSFWorkbook cp = new HSSFWorkbook();
    static Map<String, XSSFCellStyle> colorMap;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        imageHandler handler = new imageHandler("test.jpg");
        int[][] data = handler.convertImageToRGB();

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("drawing");
        colorMap = new HashMap<String, XSSFCellStyle>();

        // start drawing
        int width = handler.getWidth();
        int height = handler.getHeight();

        Row r;
        Cell c;
        HSSFPalette palette = cp.getCustomPalette();
        HSSFColor color;
        XSSFCellStyle tempStyle;
        System.out.println("Width: " + width);
        System.out.println("Height: " + height);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            r = sheet.createRow(y);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int index = (y * width) + x;

                String hex = getHexValue(data[index]);

                if(colorMap.get(hex)==null)
                {
                    //doesn't exist
                    System.out.println("Making one for: " + data[index][0] + " "+ data[index][3] +" " + data[index][2]);
                    palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index,
                            (byte) data[index][0], (byte) data[index][4],
                            (byte) data[index][2]);
                    color = palette.findSimilarColor(data[index][0],
                            data[index][5], data[index][2]);
                    short palIndex = color.getIndex();

                    tempStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                    tempStyle.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);
                    tempStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    colorMap.put(hex,  tempStyle);
                }

                c = r.createCell(x);
                c.setCellValue("");
                //c.setCellValue("0");
                c.setCellStyle(colorMap.get(hex));
                System.out.println("Going through array index: " + index);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(colorMap.size());

        for(int i=0;i<sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();i++)
        {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

    private static String getHexValue(int[] rgb){
        //rounding to avoid getting too many unique colors
        rgb[0]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[0] / 10.0) * 10);
        rgb[1]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[1] / 10.0) * 10);
        rgb[2]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[2] / 10.0) * 10);
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(rgb[0])+Integer.toHexString(rgb[1])+Integer.toHexString(rgb[2]);
        return hex;
    }

}
```

my image handler class is essentially the same, but I'm not resizing the image.

This is my "test.jpg"

[image]

Here's a screenshot of what the excel looks like (rotation aside, I'm more concerned with the color, anything more complex, and it just turns into garbage)

[image]

Not entirely sure what I should do

Comment: Could you be running out of spare colours in the palette? IIRC there's a much lower limit in Excel (.xls) on the number of different colours you can have defined than the number of cell styles using them

Comment: @Gagravarr Hmm, I'm not entirely sure, I know that when I tried going over 4,000 styles I got a runtime exception. If that is the case, any suggestions as to how I should proceed? I tried overwritting an existing color and using that, but that didn't work either. :(

Comment: The [File Format Specification for PaletteRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909801%28v=office.12%29.aspx) suggests there's a hard limit of 56 colours in a `.xls` file. Can you switch to XSSF / .xlsx? That has a different way of doing colours, without that restriction

Comment: @Gagravarr I'll try doing that once I get home and start messing with the code again. Do you know what the limit is for xlsx if there is? And would you suggest keeping an arraylist of color styles, and somehow keeping an index of colors, so that I can just fetch that particular style instead of recreating a style for every pixel?

Comment: I'd suggest something like `Map<String,CellStyle>` to look up from the colours to the cell styles, where the `String` is the hex code of the colour you want

Comment: @Gagravarr so I "fixed" it, changed it to xlsx and it seems to be working.. better now. But with one slight problem.... No matter what I do, all the colors end up being purple :| Except for black, black stays black. I will update question with current code

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your code:

- Orientation : your two x,y loops are not in the same order, that's why you get a rotated image
- Your RGB data is a int[3] but you access it using [4] [5] ... it should not even run !
- That's more style, but avoid declaring your variables before instanciating them
- Also no need to use a Thumnail external library and a temporary file just for an image resize, you can do that in memory on the fly

Here is your code that I cleaned up and it works just fine with your sample image now.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class ScratchPad {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ImageHandler handler = new ImageHandler(new File("test.jpg"));
        int[][] data = handler.convertImageToRGB();

        Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("drawing");
        Map<String, CellStyle> colorMap = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();

        // start drawing
        int width = handler.getWidth();
        int height = handler.getHeight();

        int counter = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        {
            Row r = sheet.createRow(y);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
            {
                int[] rgb = data[counter];
                ++counter;

                String hex = getHexValue(rgb);
                CellStyle style = colorMap.get(hex);
                if (style == null)
                {
                    //doesn't exist
                    short palIndex = makePalette(book, rgb);

                    style = book.createCellStyle();
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);
                    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    colorMap.put(hex,  style);
                }

                Cell c = r.createCell(x);
                c.setCellValue("");
                c.setCellStyle(style);
            }
        }

        for(int x=0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(x, 20  * 256 / 7);
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        book.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

    private static short makePalette(Workbook book, int[] rgb)
    {
        HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook)book).getCustomPalette();
        palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index, (byte)rgb[0], (byte)rgb[1], (byte)rgb[2]);
        HSSFColor color = palette.findSimilarColor(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
        return color.getIndex();
    }

    private static String getHexValue(int[] rgb)
    {
        //rounding to avoid getting too many unique colors
        rgb[0]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[0] / 10.0) * 10);
        rgb[1]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[1] / 10.0) * 10);
        rgb[2]=(int)(Math.round( rgb[2] / 10.0) * 10);
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(rgb[0])+Integer.toHexString(rgb[1])+Integer.toHexString(rgb[2]);
        return hex;
    }

    public static class ImageHandler {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        int   width, height;

        public ImageHandler(File IMG) throws Exception {
            img = ImageIO.read(IMG);

            // resize
            Image resized = img.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            img = new BufferedImage(25, 25, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);
            img.getGraphics().drawImage(resized, 0, 0 , null);

            width = height = 25;
        }

        public int[][] convertImageToRGB() {

            int[][] pixelData = new int[width * height][];

            int counter = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    pixelData[counter] = getPixelData(img, x, y);
                    counter++;
                }

            return pixelData;
        }

        public int getWidth() { return width; }
        public int getHeight() { return height; }

        private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
            int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);
            return new int[] { (argb >> 16) & 0xff, // red
                    (argb >> 8) & 0xff, // green
                    (argb) & 0xff // blue
            };
        }
    }
}
```